# How to request JSON content in HTTP

Tags: json, http-headers

I am currently doing a coding challenge and the first step that

Comment: Fix the link so people can see what you are facing.

Comment: if the first task is too difficult for you, maybe this code challenge is not suitable for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Accept http header to do that.
See this question:

[REST API - Use the "Accept: application/json" HTTP Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209924/rest-api-use-the-accept-application-json-http-header)

You will need some http client like Postman to do this, or browser development tools.